# Airflow is flooding a worker with tasks and ignores others

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

My Airflow setup currently consists of - Airflow 1.10.1 + MySQL Backend + Celery + RabbitMQ

Physical Setup - Scheduler + Webserver + Worker1 + Worker2

My problem is, if suppose there are 10 tasks which Airflow Scheduler needs to executes on 2 workers, AIrflow floods Worker1 with a major chunk of tasks and ignores Worker2.

Example: Worker1 gets 8 tasks while Worker2 gets 2 tasks

This results in Memory errors in Worker1 as some of the tasks are very resource intensive.

I have tried setting the Worker concurrency to 8, but still Worker1 is prioritized

Machine 1:

Airflow Scheduler
Airflow WebServer
Airflow Worker (worker 2)

Machine 2:

Airflow Worker (worker 1)

As of now worker 1 is flooded with a large number of tasks to process whereas worker 2 is almost ideal.

Can I give equal priority to both these workers (load-balancing) so that all the resources are utilized.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I used the 'queue' option in each of my AIrflow tasks and then ran the workers on different machine which listened to a single queue. This still looks a bit hacky!